# Multiple CSS Background not working in mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, background-image

I can't get multiple backgrounds working in mobile Safari. I'm finding it hard to debug because it works in everything else, even desktop Safari. I've read of a potential issue when grouping into a single declaration but this does not apply to me as I am not grouping them.

Here is my code:

```
    background-color: #3394CE;
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-image: url("../images/overlay3.svg"), linear-gradient(45deg, #9dc66b 5%, #4fa49a 30%, #1579AF);
    background-position: center center, center center;
    background-size: cover, cover;
```

on iOS Safari all I can see is the background colour.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the svg, not the multiple backgrounds. Can you see the svg if that's your only background?

Comment: I removed the SVG and still couldn't see gradient, I then manually added the vendor prefix (rather than relied on autoprefixer) still nothing... it's the same with Chrome on iOS so i'm not really sure where the problem lies.

Comment: You shouldn't need a vendor prefix for background. http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

Comment: I've done a bit more research and the entire blue colour isn't the background-color, it's the last value of the linear-gradient #1579AF.. i changed that last value to red and the entire div turned red, it's like the other colours aren't being applied or are out of view.

Comment: I have the same problem in 2021 on iOS 14.2. When a linear-gradient is one of multiple background-images, it doesn't show up. Pathetic.